# how save theme or color of my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

please any one help me when I close my app the theme reback to defult theme,how can I save the theme when I pick color from colorpicker library and I use hive library to save data,
if there are any another libraries to save data better than hive please tell me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/src/block_picker.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Counter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      //theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Box? box;
  Color? z;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    openBox();
    try {
      getData();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future openBox() async {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(dir.path);
    box = await Hive.openBox('colorBox');
    return;
  }

  void saveData(val) {
    box!.put('color1', val);
  }

  void getData() {
    setState(() {
      z = Color(box!.get('color1'));
    });
  }

  int counter = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  Color color = Colors.blue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Counter"),
        backgroundColor: z,
      ),
      endDrawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [              
            ListTile(
              title: Text("pick color"),
              leading: Icon(Icons.color_lens),
              onTap: () => showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                        title: Text("select your color"),
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            BlockPicker(
                              onColorChanged: (Color value) {
                                saveData(value.value);
                 
                              },
                              pickerColor: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  getData();
                                  Navigator.pop(ctx);
                                },
                                child: Text("close"))
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              incrementCounter();
            },
            child: Text(
              '${counter}',),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I make code smaller as I can,and I remove all the style.

Answer (score 0):

Hive should work for you,

alternatively you can use
Use the [Shared Preference package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) and there you can store simple values as key pair values.Load that data in the init of the initial screen so that you can display the color as you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Install flutter hive from https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter

**Step 2**: `import 'package:hive_flutter/adapters.dart';` in your models

This class as of writing this answer contains two classes:
Color and TimeOfDay

Answer (score 0):

Use hive. This is a benchmark blog that shows hive's performance capabilities: [hive performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE1V7.png)